# Proving sequence bound which leads to bound on $e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $b_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ for positive integers $n$. In the first two parts of the problem, I have shown that $a_n \leq a_{n+1} \leq b_{n+1} \leq b_n$ for all positive integers $n$, and the problem goes on to say "Deduce that $a_n < 3$". I can't figure out how to do this last part - initially I thought, since we showed $a_n \leq b_n$, and $b_{n+1} \leq b_n$ means $\{b_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, that we could say $a_n < b_1$, but that only gives $a_n < 4$, which isn't the desired bound. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you are missing is that $|b_n - a_n| \rightarrow 0;$ therefore they have a common limit, all the $a_n$ are smaller, while all the $b_n$ are bigger than the limit, which is what we write as $e$

For any $m,n,$
$$  a_m < b_n  $$

Finally, I find $b_5 < 3$

Comment: In my Analysis course (from which the problem is taken), we haven't yet defined limits of sequences. So is there a way to do it without using that?

Comment: @Prasiortle then leave out the limit idea. If can still be proven, at your level, that all $a_m < b_n$

Comment: How can that be proven?

Comment: @Prasiortle you seem to say $a_n < b_1$ in your question. Next, see if you can prove $a_n < b_2$ and then $a_n < b_3$

Answer (score 2):

we can see $a_1\leq a_2\leq \dots a_n\leq b_n\leq b_5=2.985<3(n\geq 6)$

Comment: This is an answer to the question.  As katrina notes, $b_5=(1.2)^6<3$, which means that all values of $a$ from 5 on are less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k\frac{1}{n^k}\\&=1+1+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k}\\&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\cdots\cdot\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\\&<2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\\&<2+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\\&=3.
\end{align}
That’s what we want.